# How to read object string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, jqzoom

I am getting this object value as string

`'{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: 'http://www.website.com/image.jpg',largeimage: 'http://www.website.com/image1.jpg'}'`

How can i read this using jquery? Currently i am using this following function as bellow to read this but i can't find value in `$each`

```
$(".jcarousel-item a").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("rel"));//I can find this object value here
    $.each($(this).attr("rel"), function(index, value) { 
        alert(index + ': ' + value); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you understood that what you have is an object, not an array.

Comment: This is not an array , this is an object .

Comment: That's not an array value, that's an object value. Can you use a format that is JSON compatible instead of a JavaScript format that is not possible to parse as JSON?

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to depend on jQuery for this:

```
var i;
var array =$(this).attr("rel");
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
   // do something with `array[i]`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to parse the array as this:

```
$(".jcarousel-item a").click(function() {
    var arrayData = $(this).attr("rel");
    var objData = JSON.parse(arrayData);
    // Here objData is a JSON, you can access how this
    alert(objData.gallery);
    alert(objData.smallimage);
    alert(objData.largeimage);
});
```